# Three JS animesh rewrite or fix. It won't play in the new version even if MorphAnimMesh.js is included

Tags: animation, three.js, mesh

Here it is the code, it is the "webgl_terrain_dynamic" example rewriten to include the birds.

This is the new example, without the birds: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html

This is the old example that works with birds - and the old version of three.js: http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html

This is the code I've made. It all works but the birds do not move and they also look a bit pixelated on textures (especially the parrot).

```
                // MORPHS

function addMorph( geometry, speed, duration, x, y, z ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffaa55, morphTargets: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );

    var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );

    meshAnim.speed = speed;
    meshAnim.duration = duration;
    meshAnim.time = 600 * Math.random();

    meshAnim.position.set( x, y, z );
    meshAnim.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;

    meshAnim.castShadow = true;
    meshAnim.receiveShadow = false;

    scene.add( meshAnim );

    morphs.push( meshAnim );

    //renderer.initWebGLObjects( scene );
}
```

```
function morphColorsToFaceColors( geometry ) {

    if ( geometry.morphColors && geometry.morphColors.length ) {

        var colorMap = geometry.morphColors[ 0 ];

        for ( var i = 0; i < colorMap.colors.length; i ++ ) {

            geometry.faces[ i ].color = colorMap.colors[ i ];
        }
    }
}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

var startX = -3000;

loader.load( "models/animated/parrot.js", function( geometry ) {

    morphColorsToFaceColors( geometry );
    addMorph( geometry, 250, 500, startX -500, 500, 700 );
    addMorph( geometry, 250, 500, startX - Math.random() * 500, 500, -200 );
    addMorph( geometry, 250, 500, startX - Math.random() * 500, 500, 200 );
    addMorph( geometry, 250, 500, startX - Math.random() * 500, 500, 1000 );

} );

loader.load( "models/animated/flamingo.js", function( geometry ) {

    morphColorsToFaceColors( geometry );
    addMorph( geometry, 500, 1000, startX - Math.random() * 500, 350, 40 );

} );

loader.load( "models/animated/stork.js", function( geometry ) {

    morphColorsToFaceColors( geometry );
    addMorph( geometry, 350, 1000, startX - Math.random() * 500, 350, 340 );

} );

// PRE-INIT

// renderer.initWebGLObjects( scene );
```

... in function render() I also added this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < morphs.length; i ++ ) {

    morph = morphs[ i ];

    morph.updateAnimation( 1000 * delta );

    morph.position.x += morph.speed * delta;

    if ( morph.position.x  > 2000 )  {

        morph.position.x = -1500 - Math.random() * 500;
    }
```

I als found this post that doesn't really help me: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8488

We need this code to export VR movies to help children in foster homes learn about emotions (the solution is more complex but the birds are really nice, we know - from experience - they'll love them).

I am no expert in Three.js and I do what I can. Thank you for your help and a respectful answer. :) You guys really helped me, I searched a lot to make the code so far. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) I just solved it this way:

In MorphAnimMesh.js
I defined the variable clip like this:
    var clip = this.geometry.animations[ 0 ];

instead of
    var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName( this, label );

and then called mesh.playAnimation(0.0003); in the function where I add the morph.

I hope it helps somebody. :)